# Which build artifacts should I keep for my Android app?

Tags: android, build, continuous-integration

I'm using Jenkins to build my Android app regularly. Which files should I archive in case I need them later on? For example, on iOS, the dSYM file is needed to symbolicate stack traces later on. Is there any such need for Android?

These are the files that are generated when I make a debug build (`ant clean debug`). Basically the same list is generated for a release build.

- Application-debug-unaligned.apk
- Application-debug.apk
- Application-debug-unaligned.apk.d
- Application.ap_
- Application.ap_.d
- classes.dex.d
- build.prop
- classes.dex
- classes
- res

Comment: If you use ProGuard, you should save the ProGuard directory (mapping.txt, dump.txt, etc.) for mapping obfuscated stack traces.

Answer (score 0):

You can archive all the .apk files. The files that needs to be uploaded to market its the one which has to be signed. The filename will usually be in the format appname-release.apk. It should be generated with release task provided the signing certificate is supplied during build.